# Embedded Form Throwing An Error in IE

Tags: form, internet-explorer

I have an embedded form on a page in SharePoint 2013. The form is from a vendor's website and is a registration/waiver form. There are three steps to the form: registration, watch a safety video, then fill out waiver.  The form functions fine in Chrome, but after you complete the registration portion in IE, there is an error "An Error Was Encountered. The action you have requested is not allowed".  The form works in IE when not embedded on the page though, so it must be something on the page that is causing the error.  This is the code I am using for the iframe.

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9"><iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://lw.golfboard.com/liability_waiver/new_rider/360/TexConsolverGolfCourse"></iframe></div>
```

The page is: http://www.golfwichita.com/Pages/GolfBoard.aspx

Comment: Add the site as trusted site in IE.

Answer (score 0):

You're embedding an https resource within an http site. This may not work in IE. It could quite possibly be an issue with display mixed content. What does your console log show within IE? I would check there first.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2009/06/22/handling-mixed-httpshttps-content/